# Udev rule to distinguish wireless and wired interfaces

Tags: udev, network-interface

I'm trying to set up an Arch installation on a USB thumb drive and I would like to have my network interface names stay the same regardless of which machine (physical or virtual) I plug my thumb drive into.

To do this, I would like to write `udev` rules based on whether an interface is wired or wireless. I have tried the following rules and they failed to rename the interfaces:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net",ACTION=="add",ATTR{ifindex}==2,NAME=eth0
SUBSYSTEM=="net",ACTION=="add",ATTR{ifindex}==3,NAME=wlan0
```

This is, of course, based on the naive assumption that the wired interface will be listed second and the wireless third (after the loopback).

My questions are:

1. Why did the rules fail to rename the interfaces? How can I debug this failure?
2. Is there a more robust way to detect whether an interface is wired or wireless
3. **Bonus:** For the sake of simplicity, I'm assuming that any machine I connect to will have at most one interface of each type. Is there a way of handling multiple wired/wireless interfaces?

Comment: First, check what udev sees as the attributes of each device using `udevadm info -p /sys/class/net/wlan0` and `udevadm info -p /sys/class/net/eth0` and see if the ifindexes match what you expect.

Comment: As for matching in a smarter way, I see a line `E: DEVTYPE=wlan` in the output for my `wlan0` interface that looks like a promising way to check for a wireless interface.

Answer (score 4):

If it helps, the (now deprecated in favour if a different naming scheme) `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` files that is used exactly for that purpose matched on MAC address, and not on index. And I really *really* wouldn't rely on the index, there's *no* guarantee the network interfaces are created in any particular order. Here is what it looks like this on my machine:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:11:22:33:44:55", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="11:22:33:44:55:66", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

This file is created automatically, and I've no idea why they included an additional attribute for `eth0`. Modify as required for your system. As mentioned in the comment above, use `udevadm info -p /sys/class/net/wlan0` etc. to get the full list of attributes.